# Difference of elements of an array with all element of another array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, element

Suppose I have two arrays of different sizes. Say `A=[10;12;13;17;18];` and `B=[20;22;23;17;26;30;32];`. The output, C will be as follows:

```
   [10, 8,  7,  3,  2;
    12, 10, 9,  5,  4;
    13, 11, 10, 6,  5;
    7,  5,  4,  0,  -1;
    16, 14, 13, 9,  8;
    20, 18, 17, 13, 12;
    22, 20, 19, 15, 14].
```

Each column of C is obtained by taking difference between all elements of B with a specific element of A. For example, the first column of C is obtained by taking the difference of all elements of B with first element of A, i.e., 10. If the dimension of A is (m-by-1) and B is (n-by-1), then C will have dimension (n-by-m).

Comment: Just change one to a row vector and subtract:  C = B - A'

Comment: The dimensions of A and B are different.

Comment: James Tursa's comment is the way to go. Just make sure to use `.'` instead of `'` in case you have complex values. Also, for old Matlab versions you need `bsxfun(@minus, B, A.')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this block of code.

```
clear;
clc;

A=[10;12;13;17;18];
B=[20;22;23;17;26;30;32];

m = length(A);
n = length(B);

C = zeros(n,m);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        C(j,i) = B(j) - A(i);
    end
end

disp(C)
```